# SQL WHERE clause to use multiple wildcards

Tags: sql, substring, where-clause, wildcard, regexp-substr

I have to write a query to fetch rows for 100+ diagnosis codes. What can be an optimal SQL query ? Below are the details of what I have:

Table:

| Diagnosis_Cd | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A00 | Cholera |
| A000 | Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae |
| A001 | Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor |
| .... |  |

Lookup Diagnosis Code list has only the first 3 characters. This is how the query was written when the list was small.

```
select Diagnosis_Cd
  from <table>
 where Diagnosis_Cd like 'A00%'
    or Diagnosis_Cd like 'B00%'
    or Diagnosis_Cd like 'N00%'
    ...
```

But now the list has more than 200 diagnosis codes to lookup. Below is what I could come with, so far, considering the easiness to construct the WHERE clause.

```
WITH temp AS 
(select substring(Diagnosis_Cd, 1, 3) as col1
   from <table>)
select col1
  from temp
 where col1 in ('A00', 
                'B00', 
                'N00',
                ...)
```

Is there a better way to do it ? "regexp" cannot seem to use wildcard. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Not sure if it's in every RDMBS, but at least some of them use `_` for a single character -- so I think `like '_00%'` would work

Comment: Diagnosis codes won't necessarily have a common format in some groupers, so there may be occasions where `A00%` are related to `B10%`. You may want to download a CCS grouper table from AHRQ. That has some standard groups that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

First position is a letter in the range A-Z, then a 0, then a 0, then anything.

```
select Diagnosis_Cd
  from <table>
 where Diagnosis_Cd like '[A-Z][0][0]%'
```